# Displaying notification badge on BottomNavigationBar's Icon

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to display notification badge (a colored **marble**) on the **top right corner** of BottomNavigationBar's **Icon** widget when a new message has arrived in the inbox tab. It is similar to https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-badges.html but for my case it is displayed in-app.

Any tips to paint the overlay on existing icon to create a **custom** Icon class?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes. It can be done by stacking two icons using the `Stack` and `Positioned` widget.

```
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: new Text('Home'),
        icon: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(Icons.home),
            new Positioned(  // draw a red marble
              top: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 8.0, 
                color: Colors.redAccent),
            )
          ]
        ),
      )
```

Comment: This covers my whole icon. The position has to be someting negative but this will cut the circle

Comment: @Jones, try `overflow: Overflow.visible` in Stack and that should fix the clipping

Comment: its deprecated right now. what is your alternative solution?

Comment: @Mehrdad the alternative is ```clipBehavior``` 

And ```clipBehavior: Clip.none``` is the alternative for ```overflow: Overflow.visible```

Answer (score 154):

One more variation of counting badge (implemented with Stack of Icon and wrapped in Container Text, which stretched when counter increase):

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Icon(Icons.notifications),
      new Positioned(
        right: 0,
        child: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          ),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minWidth: 12,
            minHeight: 12,
          ),
          child: new Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 8,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
  title: Text('Notifications'),
),
```

[image: BottomNavigationBar item counting badge]

Comment: How do you adjust the size of the red circle?

Comment: The red circle is `Container` so it is adjusted automatically, but, with proper `constraints` and `decoration`, it displayed as the circle.

Comment: Not working, when I add this code it showing code in red color

Comment: @Midhilaj it seems that you have an error in some other place because this code works even in DartPad - https://dartpad.dev/65b65e2d7cdb8a8d934e1f1fb81650ad

Comment: @ych a little better if you add this line before the Positioned.   if(_counter > 0)

Comment: This covers my whole icon. The position has to be someting negative but this will cut the circle

Comment: @Jones you can change clip behavior in the Stack widget. `clipBehavior: Clip.none` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 32):

#### Update (use `Badge`):

[image]

```dart
BottomNavigationBar(
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      label: 'Call',
      icon: Badge(
        label: Text('12'),
        child: Icon(Icons.call),
      ),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      label: 'Messages',
      icon: Badge(
        label: Text('20'),
        child: Icon(Icons.mail),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

---

#### Old answer:

[image]

If you also want to handle `onTap` with some splash, use this widget, you can further customize it according to your needs:

***You don't need to depend on a package, just copy this class*:**

```dart
class NamedIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData iconData;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final int notificationCount;

  const NamedIcon({
    Key? key,
    this.onTap,
    required this.text,
    required this.iconData,
    this.notificationCount = 0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        width: 72,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(iconData),
                Text(text, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6, vertical: 2),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('$notificationCount'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('AppBar'),
    actions: [
      NamedIcon(
        text: 'Inbox',
        iconData: Icons.notifications,
        notificationCount: 11,
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      NamedIcon(
        text: 'Mails',
        iconData: Icons.mail,
        notificationCount: 1,
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 19):

There is a nice package[0] that makes this as simple as using the following instead of an Icon:

```
Badge(
  badgeContent: Text('3'),
  child: Icon(Icons.settings),
)
```

0: https://pub.dev/packages/badges

Answer (score 7):

You can also nest the Stacks. For instance, if you would like to add item_count on the shopping_cart icon, you can do this:

```
icon: new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                new Positioned(
                  top: 1.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: new Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Icon(Icons.brightness_1,
                          size: 18.0, color: Colors.green[800]),
                      new Positioned(
                        top: 1.0,
                        right: 4.0,
                        child: new Text(item_count,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score 6):

```
new BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      fixedColor: const Color(0xFF2845E7),
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(
            Icons.home,
          ),
          title: new Text(
            "Home",
          ),
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.call,
            ),
            title: new Text(
              "Calls",
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.camera_alt,
            ),
            title: new Text(
              "Camera",
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.favorite),
              new Positioned(
                  top: -1.0,
                  right: -1.0,
                  child: new Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Icon(
                        Icons.brightness_1,
                        size: 12.0,
                        color: const Color(0xFF2845E7),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ))
            ]),
            title: new Text(
              "Stories",
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
            ),
            title: new Text(
              "Contacts",
            )),
      ],
      onTap: (){},
      currentIndex: 0,
    ),
```

[image: BottomNavigationBar with notification badge on favorite icon]

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `Stack` to render the marble on top of the `Icon`, wrapping the marble in a `Positioned`, `Align`, or `FractionallySizedBox` to position it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Before Feb 2022, I have been using the Stack widget, but lately I start using Badges Package after flutter team talked about it in the widget of the week series
it makes thing easier and simple:
[video from flutter YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CIHLJHVoN8)

the package: [Badges for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

example:

```
                 BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Badge(
                    showBadge: true,
                    badgeContent: Text('6', style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    animationType:  BadgeAnimationType.scale,
                    shape: BadgeShape.circle,
                    //position: BadgePosition.center(),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
                  ),
                  label: 'Notifications',
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 32,
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications,color: AshtarColors.dark_blue,),
              onPressed: () {
                log("notification");
              },
            ),
            new Positioned(
              top: 3,
              right: 0,
              child: new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                ),
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: 15,
                  minHeight: 15,
                ),
                child: new Text('11',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 11,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Flutter 3.7 the Badge widget was introduced in the [Material library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Badge-class.html).
Therefore if you still want to use the badges package be sure to prefix it like this in order to avoid ambiguous imports:

`import 'package:badges/badges.dart' as badges;`

Answer (score 0):

Just add both smallsize and largesize property.

```
  child: const Badge(
     largeSize: 10.00,
     smallSize: 10.00,
     child: Icon(Icons.notifications_none_rounded),
  ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Transparent appBar without navigation icon and bell icon:

```
appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    title: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Text('Find Your Favorite drink',
        style: kTitle,
      ),
    ),
    actions: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0,top: 5,bottom: 5),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          height: 20,
          width: 45,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Icon(Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
                    color: Color(0xFFFEA70B),
                  ),
                  new Positioned(  // draw a red marble
                    top: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    child: new Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 8.0,
                        color: Color(0xFFFF4545)),
                  )
                ]
            ),
            onPressed: (){},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```