# Flutter BottomNavigationBarItem accepts only Icon and no other widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

In our Flutter Cupertino project, we need to show a badge on one of the bottom bar icons. How many articles are already in the shopping cart to be precise.

I've tried different widgets and solutions provided here, but the `BottomNavigationBarItem` accepts only `icon: Icon(..)` and nothing else. If I, for example, put `icon: Stack(..)` instead of the `icon: Icon(..)`, there are error messages shown, for example
"Invalid const value..."

Here is some sample code:

```dart
class CupertinoStoreHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
            title: Text('Kühlschrank'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.profile_circled),
            title: Text('Konto'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.shopping_cart),
            title: Text('Warenkorb'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

So if I can not put anything instead of the `Icon(..)`. No other widget, no `Stack(..)`.

Why? How can I put some other widget, like for example `Badge(..)`:

```
badges: ^1.0.2
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
```

This question is different from the possible duplicate, because I already tried the solution posted there and still can not use Stack(..) but only Icon(..).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying notification badge on BottomNavigationBar's Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155104/displaying-notification-badge-on-bottomnavigationbars-icon)

Comment: Using a Stack for the icon property works for me. Whats the exact error message when you try it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried reproducing the problem, but it does work after changing a few things. First of all the `icon` property accepts a `Widget` and therefore not only an `Icon`, so this is not the problem.

I did notice however, in `items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[` you should remove the `const` keyword as it is not necessary and also not constant.

And lastly, you need to add a tab builder to `CupertinoTabScaffold` this basically returns what's displayed above the bottom navigation bar.

Your final code then looks like this:

```dart
return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
      },
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Badge(
              badgeContent: Text('3'),
              child: Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
            title: Text('Kühlschrank'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.profile_circled),
            title: Text('Konto'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.shopping_cart),
            title: Text('Warenkorb'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```