# Add text widget on BottomNavigationBarItem icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a small text widget containing a number representing the number of messages that a user received on the bottom right side of the Bottom NavigationBarItem. So if the user has no new messages the text does not appear, and if he has 3 new messages for example, a small circle widget containing "3" appears on the Messages icon.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.message,
            ),
            title: Text('Messages'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
            title: Text('Profile'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: 1,
        onTap: (_onItemTapped),
      )
```

Comment: I fail to see what indicates that you deal with messages in your code, did you forger to include that?

Comment: @JulienLachal I only want to display a text widget on the icon of the BottomNavigationBarItem. This is the only thing I am not able to do.

Comment: yes but, did you try? and if so, how?

Comment: @JulienLachal sure I tried. I couldn't find any attribute in BottomNavigationBarItem that allows me to do so.

Comment: @JulienLachal have a look here in stack overflow on the "Recent inbox messages" icon, when you receive new message, how it shows "1" on the icon. I want to do the same.

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155104/displaying-notification-badge-on-bottomnavigationbars-icon

Comment: @JulienLachal I tried the proposed answers, the icon attribute is not accepting a Stack. Can you try it on your side. Maybe in latest version it is not possible to use Stack for icon attribute!

Comment: @JulienLachal It worked. I was trying to copy-paste the Stack and it was giving error. I had to erase the BottomNavigationBar and replace it to work. I think it was an IDE (Android Studio) problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an icon, you can put any widget.
I put there a regular stack with two icons and
It works fine:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.message),
            Positioned(
              top: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.brightness_1,
                size: 8.0,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('Messages'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: 1,
  ),
```

Comment: If you are experiencing any problems, try removing const before the array in your example

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. May your problem will be solved. After v1.19.0 title was replaced with the label. so use this.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "home"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: "explore"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), label: "notification"),
    ],
  ),
```