# Flutter positioned widget cuts off content

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I'm attempting to create a notification widget with a number overlay.

I've followed the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155104/displaying-notification-badge-on-bottomnavigationbars-icon) to make the widget.

Using this code (not specifying a position), produces the following widget: [image: Widget]

```
Widget iconWidget() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
            child: Container(
          child: Icon(
            icon,
            color: color,
          ),
        )),
        Positioned(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            child: Text('$count',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)),
            backgroundColor: count == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

However, as soon as I specify a position (right: 0), my widget gets gut off: [image]

```
Widget iconWidget() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
            child: Container(
          child: Icon(
            icon,
            color: color,
          ),
        )),
        Positioned(
          right: 0,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            child: Text('$count',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)),
            backgroundColor: count == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

My widget is being created as an icon within a tab controller:

```
Tab(
  icon: IconWithCount(
          icon: FlutterIcons.heartbeat_faw5s,
          color: Colors.red,
          count: 5)
      .iconWidget(),
),
```

Full class creating the widget:

```
class IconWithCount {
  final IconData icon;
  final int count;
  final Color color;
  IconWithCount({
    this.icon,
    this.count,
    this.color,
  });

  Widget iconWidget() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
            child: Container(
          child: Icon(
            icon,
            color: color,
          ),
        )),
        Positioned(
          right: 0,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            child: Text('$count',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)),
            backgroundColor: count == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem in using first code?

Comment: I'm wanting to position the counter on the bottom right of the icon. when I attempt to do so it's cut off.

Comment: Use the alignment propert of stack alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nehal. Unfortunately, same outcome as the first image I posted.

Comment: In positioned widget mention both the right and bottom properties to 0. Also I think you need to give a height or width to the Icon inside the stack for this to work

Answer (score 28):

**`overflow` is Deprecated. Use this:**

```dart
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none, // <---
  children: [],
)
```

Answer (score 10):

Inside the stack , just add this

```
overflow: Overflow.visible,
```

Comment: This answer is deprecated as of 2021. Use `clipBehavior: Clip.none`instead.