# Add badge in FloatingNavbar flutter

Tags: flutter

I created FloatingNavbar in bottomnavigation. I want to add badge on top cart of cart icon in FloatingNavbar. When i tried with normal bottomnavigation it is working but  when i tried with FloatingNavbar not wokring. Because normal bottomnavigation icon is widgets but In FloatingNavbar it's icondata. That's why it is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Code :

```
 return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onWillPop,
  child:   Scaffold(

      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      //  appBar: HomeAppBar(),
    extendBody: false,
      body: _tabs[_selectedIndex],
    bottomNavigationBar: FloatingNavbar(

       currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      items: itemsFloating,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[500],
      fontSize: 8,

      selectedItemColor: Colors.orange[300],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),

  ),
);
 List<FloatingNavbarItem> itemsFloating =[
FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.home

    , title: 'Home'),
FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.search, title: 'Search'),
FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.shopping_cart, title: 'Cart'),
FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.people, title: 'Membership'),
FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.person_outline, title: 'Profile'),
];
```

Badge :

```
 icon: Badge(
          showBadge: true,
          badgeContent: Text(
            badgeData,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
```

Comment: use Stack and visibility widget

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155104/displaying-notification-badge-on-bottomnavigationbars-icon you can refer this post  answer too

Comment: Stack also tried not working, FloatingNavbarItem icon accepting only icondata not other widgets